# Building dynamic routes with single or multiple parameters coming from database

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

Below are the links.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Basic Item Definition",
    "routerLink": "/itemmaint/basicitemdefinition",
    "param1": "35",
    "param2": "",
    "parentId": " 0"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "General Product Attributes",
    "routerLink": "/itemmaint/generalproductattributes",
    "param1": "35",
    "param2": "edit",
    "parentId": " 0"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Shipper Item Composition",
    "routerLink": "/itemmaint/shipperitem",
    "param1": "35",
    "param2": "",
    "parentId": " 0"
  }
]
```

Above links are from the database and for some of the links has two params and some has one parameter:

```
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let lnkObj of itemSummarylinks" class="app-sidenav-content">
      <a [routerLink]="buildDynamicRoutes(lnkObj)">
                        {{link.name}}
      </a>
  </mat-list-item>
```

In component:

```
buildDynamicRoutes(lnkObj)
{
  //how to build the dynamic routes here based on the params
  //if its single param then route should be /itemmaint/basicitemdefinition/35
  //if its double param it should be /itemmaint/basicitemdefinition/35/edit
}
```

in routes:

```
 { path: 'basicitemdefinition:id', component: BasicItemDefinitionDetailComponent },
  { path: 'generalproductattributes:id:edit', component: GeneralProductAttributesDetailComponent }
```

I am unable to do string interpolation while building dynamic routes with dynamic parameters so trying this approach.

Answer (score 0):

this depends if you want to completely abstract this out or just use param1/param2. In the case of param1/param2 i would do something like this:

```
if (lnkObj.param2){
        //do the logic if there is a param 2
    } else {
        //do the logic for other cases
    }

// this can be simplified into:
return linkObj.param2 ? '/itemmaint/basicitemdefinition/35/edit' : '/itemmaint/basicitemdefinition/35';
```

If you want to abstract that out since you might want to include other parameters in the future, i would make params array and then just check the length of that array and you will know how many params you have.

```
const arr = ['param1', 'param2']
const lengthOfArray = arr.length()
// lengthOfArray will be 2 so you know you have two params and then do the logic
```

Hope this helps you.